# setting HttpContext.Current.User from JWT Token

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, owin, jwt

I'm using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt nuget package to secure my webapi. It's setting the HttpContext.Current.User as expected when I'm passing the token to the webapi as a header into my requests.

As the business logic is encapsulated, I could not find the moment that HttpContext.Current.User is being setted.

Instead of searching for the right claim using identity.Claims all the time, I would like to extract the information that I need, and set a custom class as HttpContext.Current.User. Is it possible using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what you mean. The HttpContext.Current.User is set automatically the moment your token is valid (matching the secret and not expired). 
What you could do is write some extension methods to retrieve other values. For example:

```
public static class IdentityHelpers
{
    public static string GetUserId(this IIdentity identity) 
    {
        ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = identity as ClaimsIdentity;

        if (claimsIdentity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "UserId") != null) {
            return claimsIdentity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "UserId").Value;
        }

        return "0";
    }

    public static string GetUserName(this IIdentity identity) 
    {
        return identity.Name;
    }
}
```

You will then be able to call for example:

```
HttpContext.Current.user.GetUserName();
```

or

```
HttpContext.Current.User.GetUserId();
```

wherever you include that class.

Comment: Right now I`m solving this way. I would like to intercept the moment that Owin sets this HttpContext.Current.User and set a custom class with the values extracted from the claims.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you then. I find that whole Owin concept pretty fuzzy and i also have a lot of helper methods that retrieve my claims like i showed in my answer to overcome this. I'll follow this question to hopefully have a good answer